# Why .NET Framework components are not available for .NET 6.0 forms

Tags: .net, visual-studio, winforms

My .NET 6.0 WinForms app works fine with UI controls imported from .NET Framework 4.5 dll, both in run-time and design-time. The only problem the controls are grayed out in Toolbox and so must be placed on app's forms by the code. Any solution for that? Visual Studio 2022.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/whats-new-in-windows-forms-in-net-6-0-preview-5/#more-runtime-designers

> In .NET Core we have ported a number of API that should enable
> building a general purpose designer. So we still have to placed the
> controls on app's forms by the code. Or we can create the WinForm
> project based on the framework, but not core.

Comment: NET Framework control works fine both in design-time and run-time on NET 6.0 form. I see no reasons why it can't be provided by Toobox.